# how do you prevent the result of a formula from changing with the filters in SSAS?

Tags: powerbi, ssas, dax, custom-data-attribute

First of all, I have a security `CustomData()` that is filtering data depending on **IdCentre** of the table **Dim_Centre**.

```
IdCentre | UserName
--------------------
7613     |  Jame_R
7610     | Hugo_T
```

On the other hand, I have a table **Fact_Control** that has the total controls made by each **Center** depending on the **type (1,2)**.

```
Date_Ctl |IdCentre|Departement|Type_Ctl| Total_Ctl
20200201   7613      76           1        10
20200202   7613      76           2         5
20200202   7613      76           1         4
20200202   7610      76           1        10
20200202   7610      76           2         7
20200203   7610      76           2         3
20200203   7610      76           1         5
```

I need a formula that calculates the **number of controls** made per department.
This formula cannot change depending on the center, as there are centers that do not work every day.

**for example:**
`Total_CTL_Dep = 44`
If I filter by the center **7613**  the `total_Ctl_Dep` change to **19** but I want to keep the **44**.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: SSAS Multidimensional or Tabular? And I assume Power BI is live connecting to SSAS rather than importing some tables from SSAS?

Comment: Hi, it is **tabular** model. You are right, PowerBi is connecting to SSAS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is you just need a single number that is unfiltered by row level security then the easiest way to accomplish this is by creating a hidden calculated table. Calculated tables are calculated at processing time outside without row level security being applied. (You could put row level security over the resulting calculated table but in this instance you wouldn’t want to.) ensure the new Fact_Control_Dep calculated table has no relationships to other tables (so that row level security won’t filter its rows).

```
Fact_Control_Dep = ROW("Total_CTL_Dep", SUM(Fact_Control[Total_Ctl]))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering me. I just solved the issue. I created 2 new tables for creating measures. Then, I use them as Fact Tables. In fact, using them as fact tables allows me to create any measure, as they are linked to other dimensions, these will respect the security and will not change my data